# Customer Registration Form Magento to CMS Pages or Static Blocks

Tags: magento

How can I add Magento's Registration Form to any CMS Page I want or into a Static Block so that I can easily add it wherever it is required?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for any **CMS pages** or **Static block**.

```
{{block type ="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_register" template="/customer/form/register.phtml" }}
```

Comment: Awesome mate Thanks!